# searching example for data loss by multiple access via threads (in C)

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

I am searching an example for data loss by a concurrent access from two or more threads. Have anyone an idea, how I could do that? (in C)

In the second step I want to fix the problem with mutex or smth like that.

But it would help just to have an idea how to do the data loss!

greetings

Comment: A simple increment where you lose an increment because one of the threads overwrites the others change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a simple linked list, start two thread : one adding and one deleting.

I guarante you a beautiful sigsev after a while.
The mutex will help keep your linked list clean.